# Merging cells values in selected range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create simple macro (since I have some repetitive work) that would merge (but not merge in excel way of joining two cells, but moving value of rest of cells to the first one) values.
I thought I could loop through selection, and join with *&* symbol second cell to first, then third to first and so.
So I have something like this:

```
Sub scal()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng
     'code here
Next cell

End Sub
```

This way I can maniopulate each cell, but how can I do merging (once again not merging-merging like making two cells one, but moving value of one to other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub scal()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim v As Variant

    Set rng = Selection
    For Each cell In rng
         v = v & cell.Value
    Next cell
    rng.ClearContents
    rng.Cells(1, 1) = v
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, It was so easy that I feel stupid now. I just haven't thought about getting extra variable. Thanks!